# Swift warning - integer overflows when converted from 'Builtin.Int32' to 'Builtin.Int8'

Tags: swift, int, warnings

I am getting the following warning, with no reference to the line in which it is happening:

```
warning: integer overflows when converted from 'Builtin.Int32' to 'Builtin.Int8'
```

The warning arises in this code:

```
extension NSPoint {

func ToString() -> String {
    return "(" + self.x.description + "," + self.y.description + ")"
}

func Plus(toBeAdded : NSPoint) -> NSPoint {
    return NSPoint(x: self.x + toBeAdded.x, y: self.y + toBeAdded.y)
}

func Minus(toBeMinused : NSPoint) -> NSPoint {
    return NSPoint(x: self.x - toBeMinused.x, y: self.y - toBeMinused.y)
}

static func fromScalar(scalar : Int) -> NSPoint {
    return NSPoint(x: scalar, y: scalar)
}
}
```

The NSPoint initializer takes Int, so I don't immediately know why it would be this - any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a bug, and is caused by the  `description` method
in your `ToString()` method. The same warning already occurs with

```
let x = CGFloat(12.0)
let s = x.description
```

As a workaround, you can use string interpolation instead:

```
func ToString() -> String {
    return "(\(self.x),\(self.y))"
}
```

or just

```
func ToString() -> String {
    return "\(self)"
}
```

which gives the same result.